# Write java class with nested Map to custom json format using Gson

Tags: java, json, gson

What Java data structure can be used to serialize to the following Json which have a set of child objects?

Example:

```
{
    "John": {
        "Type": "Person",
        "age": 30,
        "Sean": {
            "Type": "child",
            "age": 3
        },
        "Julian": {
            "Type": "child",
            "age": 4
        }
    },
    "Paul": {
        "Type": "Person",
        "age": 64,
        "Stella": {
            "Type": "child",
            "age": 10
        },
        "James": {
            "Type": "child",
            "age": 12
        }
    }
}
```

Writing John and Paul can be done by: `Map<String,Person>` but i cannot figure out how to nest the Child without having the 'children' property.

Example:

```
{
    "John": {
        "Type": "Person",
        "age": 30,
        "children": {
            "Sean": {
                "Type": "child",
                "age": 3
            },
            "Julian": {
                "Type": "child",
                "age": 4
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am not sure it is relevant, but Gson is being used to create the Json file

Comment: let us know what you have tried

Comment: I have tried registering a Gson TypeAdapter that override the `write` for the children Map, I wasn't able to get it to work as expected and it seems like a very cumbersome solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure wheher this is possible with GSON though it's possible with Jackson.

With GSON you can try custom `JsonSerializer`, which might look something like this:

```
private static class PersonTypeSerializer implements JsonSerializer<Person> {

    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(Person person, Type type, JsonSerializationContext jsonSerializationContext) {
        JsonObject personJson = personToJson(person);
        for (Map.Entry<String, Person> child : person.getChildren().entrySet()) {
            personJson.add(child.getKey(), personToJson(child.getValue()));
        }
        return personJson;
    }

    private static JsonObject personToJson(Person person) {
        JsonObject personJson = new JsonObject();
        personJson.addProperty("Type", person.getType());
        personJson.addProperty("age", person.getAge());

        return personJson;
    }
}
```

and register to GSON instance like this:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Person.class, new PersonTypeSerializer())
                             .create();
```

Note that code assumes that both type `"Person"` and `"child"` are represented by the same `Person` class. It should be pretty easy to modify this if not.

Comment: I am looking to serialize some data structure to the Example Json, the question is how to represent the Json example with a Java class

Comment: Ah, right! Sorry for misunderstanding. I've edited the original answer. The idea behind stays the same. Again I'm not sure whether this can be done by single datastructre using GSON.